# Booting issues with pi 4

Tags: pi-4, noobs

My raspberry pi isn't booting, I get the rainbow splash screen then the raspberry pi icon then the system crashes with no logs or any reason for crashing. I have tried the software NOOBS and followed a guide on how to use it then when the system was done installing the os it would crash.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use NOOBS. It is no longer supported.

Install Raspberry Pi OS onto the sd card using Pi Imager:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try install a clean image using [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) and avoid NOOBs (there's potentially some bad NOOBS images around, and flashing yourself ensures you're getting the OS from Raspberry Pi - see instructions at [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html)). If that doesn't fix it, I'd change power supplies - you want 5V and 2A - and make sure your cables are in good quality and high quality.